# Accessing multiple firebase projects

Tags: android, firebase

You can access the Firebase project from multiple Android apps, but, if my intent is to be able to access multiple projects within the same Android app?

For example, 3 projects hosted each on their own proprietary accounts and a common Android app that can access them all.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize multiple `FirebaseApp` instances yourself(this is done by google services plugin by reading google-services.json)

```
    //This builder may call more functions depending on features being used
    val secondProjectOptions = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("app id")
            .setApiKey("api key")
            .build()
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, secondProjectOptions, "secondProject")
    //Use this app instance to access various features such as db
    val secondProjectApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondProject")
```